# Is it possible to delete a particular command in history?

Tags: tcsh

I managed to get a *really* long command in my command history.  Is there a way to get rid of it so that the `history` command does not go wild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation I am seeing, you can find out where your history is stored by looking in the file:

```
/usr/share/init/tcsh/tcsh.defaults
```

For the line:

```
set histfile = ~/.tcsh_history # History file
```

Then (hopefully) you should be able to edit `~/.tcsh_history` (or whatever your actual history file comes out to be) and delete the long command.

[Reference](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwinos-users/2001/Oct/msg00421.html)

Comment: I didn't even think about editing the storage! The Ubuntu 10.4 LTS box I am on did not have a file at the location you mentioned, but it was in .history in my home directory.  I had to logout/login after doing the edit. Thanks!